# SWI Prolog foreach/2

Tags: loops, prolog, swi-prolog

Consider

```
?- length(L, 4), foreach(member(M,L),(length(M,4))).
L = [_28602, _28608, _28614, _28620].
```

vs

```
?- length(L, 4), foreach(between(1,4,I),call({L}/[I]>>(nth1(I,L,M),length(M,4)),I)).
L = [[_6010, _6016, _6022, _6028], [_6358, _6364, _6370, _6376], [_6754, _6760, _6766, _6772], [_7198, _7204, _7210, _7216]].
```

I'd like to get the latter result, but using `member` is a tidier way of expressing "all the contents".

I've tried adding some logging to debug, but I can't make heads or tails of it.

```
?- length(L, 4), foreach((member(M,L),write(M),writeln(L)),(length(M,4))).
_3400[_3400,_4060,_4066,_4072]
_3400[_4054,_3400,_4066,_4072]
_3400[_4054,_4060,_3400,_4072]
_3400[_4054,_4060,_4066,_3400]
L = [_4054, _4060, _4066, _4072].
```

And yet more convoluted logging and modification:

```
?- length(L, 3), foreach((member(M,L),write((m,M," ")),write((l,L," ")),length(M,3),write((m,M," ")),writeln((l,L))),(true)).
m,_60830, l,[_60830,_61872,_61878], m,[_61944,_61950,_61956], l,[[_61944,_61950,_61956],_61872,_61878]
m,_60830, l,[_61866,_60830,_61878], m,[_61944,_61950,_61956], l,[_61866,[_61944,_61950,_61956],_61878]
m,_60830, l,[_61866,_61872,_60830], m,[_61944,_61950,_61956], l,[_61866,_61872,[_61944,_61950,_61956]]
L = [_61866, _61872, _61878].
```

This last, in particular, leads me to suspect that any variable in the generator (the first term of `foreach`) is effectively deep-copied at the time `foreach` is called, and the copy is reset on each loop.  It'll keep structures that are already bound, but unifying any of them inside the `foreach` just unifies the copy, not the original.  Is that a correct inference?  Is there any other info I should know about how `foreach` operates?  The documentation is pretty slim.

(I did figure out a way to do what I originally wanted, I think:

```
loop(Gen, Cond) :-
    aggregate(bag(X),call(Gen,X),L),maplist(Cond,L).

?- length(L,4),loop({L}/[X]>>(member(X,L)),[X]>>(length(X,4))).
```

It's just a bit clunky.  Perhaps the specificity is good, though.)

Using SWI-Prolog version 8.0.3 for x64-win64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=foreach/2) actually says what you believe is happening:

> Each member of the conjunction is a copy of Goal, where the variables it shares with Generator are filled with the values from the corresponding solution.

One doesn't see a lot of use of `foreach/2`; `forall/2` is, I believe, more commonly used but neither of these is standard. Looking at the docs for `forall/2`, I notice this note:

> If your intent is to create variable bindings, the forall/2 control structure is inadequate. Possibly you are looking for maplist/2, findall/3 or foreach/2.

Sure enough, we can do what you're trying to do here with `maplist/2` and a lamba expression:

```
?- length(L, 4), maplist([X]>>(length(X,4)), L).
L = [[_9462, _9468, _9474, _9480], 
     [_9558, _9564, _9570, _9576], 
     [_9654, _9660, _9666, _9672], 
     [_9750, _9756, _9762, _9768]].
```

You can also do this with `findall/3`:

```
?- length(L, 4), findall(X, (member(X, L), length(X, 4)), Xs).
L = [_10432, _10438, _10444, _10450],
Xs = [[_10580, _10586, _10592, _10598], 
      [_10550, _10556, _10562, _10568], 
      [_10520, _10526, _10532, _10538], 
      [_10490, _10496, _10502, _10508]].
```

Notice that in the latter case here, the result isn't L, it's Xs.

I would consider either of these a better option than the code you came up with, which just looks a bit convoluted to me, although in general I think `aggregate` should be used more often.

Comment: "where the variables it shares with Generator are filled with the values from the corresponding solution" doesn't clearly convey that said values are effectively copies of what's been bound outside `foreach`...but, it's about as close an answer as I'm liable to get, so, ok.  And your alternative methods are better for my _particular_ example, but my intent was for a more general "for each solution X, apply it in goal Y and leave it bound"; thanks, though.  Regardless, my question was about the operation of `foreach`, so...good enough.

Comment: @Erhannis It clearly says the goal is copied. I don't think it could be more clear about that. I am also surprised that `foreach/2` uses copies, but what you're asking for is, I think, a more specific version of what `setof/3` and friends do (of which `findall/3` is one). `aggregate` is a more modern version of that. So I think you probably have the tools you need; `foreach/2` just isn't one of them.

Comment: But it _isn't_ the goal being copied.  It's the variables present specifically in Generator.  At least, that's what I asked about in my post.

Comment: @Erhannis if I copy a term and unify variables in that copy, nothing has really occurred to the original. Does the output of this query surprise you? `length(L, 4), member(X, L), copy_term(X, Y), Y = 3.`

Comment: As it turns out, in my initial example, the goal ISN'T getting copied; not explicitly.  Nor is the generator.  `foreach(member(M,L),(length(M,4)))` reduces to `\+ (member(M,L), \+ length(M,4))`.  I'm not particularly clear on the details of how `\+` works, so I can't currently provide more analysis than that.  In any case...I have a function that does what I want, so I'm good.